# change status code 500 to 404 in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-errors

I want to redirect all of my errors to one action with status code 404 in mvc 4,
I have set this to web config but when internal error happened the page is redirect to my 404 action but status code is 500

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="/_404" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">

    <error statusCode="404"
       redirect="http://www.khanoumi.com/_404"/>
<error statusCode="500"
       redirect="http://www.khanoumi.com/_404"/>
  </customErrors>
```

and also this is my action:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: The action is just to test the Error I'm guessing? You don't want an action that throws an error all the time?

Comment: The re-direct is too late in the pipline to change the status code. It's reacting to a status, not changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can force 404 error by using

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Your error message");
```

or for  Asp.Net MVC 4 you can use:

```
if (condition)
{
    return HttpNotFound("Your error message");
}
```

Also you can create custom attribute for this purpose, something like that:

```
public class HandleNotFoundAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpException = filterContext.Exception.GetBaseException() as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null && (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404 ||
                                      httpException.GetHttpCode() == 500))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                                {
                                  ViewName = "404",
                                  ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData
                                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean I have to do it in all of my actions ? it can not be a good solution, Is there any other solution that do not to do it in all actions ?